# Prolog - Manipulating the same list for several times

Tags: prolog, immutability

I am new to Prolog and trying to modify a list by deleting elements by indices.

For example:

```
remove(1,[1,2,3],Z).  
Z is [1,3].
```

However, when I try to run this predicate again, the list is sent as [1,2,3].

As far I searched, I think it cant be implemented in Prolog 
Is that true ?

And if its true, what alternatives I can try ?

I have been stuck in it for a long time and really any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the predefined predicates [nth0/3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=nth0/3) and [select/3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=select/3)

```
?- nth0(1,[1,2,3],Element),select(Element,[1,2,3],Z).
Element = 2,
Z = [1, 3] ;
false.
```

Comment: thank you for your concern, I have done java my whole life and i was wondering,Is it possible to do the same for Z, i mean sending it again and deleting one of its element by index ?

Comment: @user13052969 You absolutely need to take a look at [Clojure](https://clojure.org/about/state) then. It's a cure, but keeps the strong link to Java. Back to Prolog: The idea is that you can create a new list Z1 from an existing list Z0, leaving Z0 as it is, and if you need to modify it further, you pass that Z1 into some other predicate, obtaining a Z2 but leaving Z1 as it was. Z2 can be modified further etc. etc. Sp you generally have predicates which look like pred(StuffIn, StuffOut). Anyway, I recommend taking a look at intros: https://github.com/klaussinani/awesome-prolog#resources

Comment: Hmmm, the SWI Prolog [`library(lists)`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=lists) has no (functional/logical) equivalent of the Perl imperative/in-place-modifying [`splice`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html). SOMEONE needs to add it.

Comment: And the Wikipedia page for [Immutable object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) has nothing about Prolog. Dayum.